# QA in Office Setting?

Tags: qa-developer, office

Can you identify simple quality assurance tool in an office setting? If there is, can you list them? Any list can be of great help.

Comment: What does "in an office setting" mean here?

Comment: This question is really vague. Sounds like you need a better understanding of the problem you are trying to solve. Use the best quality assurance tool you have: your brain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The perfect example of simple quality assurance tool that can be found in an office setting would be your computer's MS Office applications. It helps in ensuring quality of your paper works and help you finished faster. I found a thread as an example that can be very helpful. Here it is http://www.techyv.com/questions/quality-assurance-software-uses-msaccess

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what "in an office setting" means here.

I use WinTask for lots of my testing.

You can find links to trials of it and other tools here. Perhaps one or more of these might help:
http://www.allthingsquality.com/2010/04/trial-versions-of-commercial-test.html